# Does the use of δέ (de, "but, and, now") in 1 Corinthians 14:35 preclude it being a mere restatement of verse 34?

Tags: greek, 1-corinthians

Some interpretations I've heard of 1 Corinthians 14:34-35 argue that because verse 35 is merely restating what is said in verse 34, and since verse 35 discusses women asking questions, therefore verse 34 also must only be discussing the asking of questions. However, since verse 35 starts out saying, "**And [δέ]** if they want to learn something..." (NKJV, emphasis mine), would this suggest that verse 35 is in addition to verse 34, rather than a mere restatement in different words? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning 1 Cor 14:34, 35, the NIV provides a good, representative translation of this verse.

> “Women should remain silent in the churches. They are not allowed to
> speak, but must be in submission, as the law says.   If they want to
> inquire about something, they should ask their own husbands at home;
> for it is disgraceful for a woman to speak in the church.”  1 Cor
> 14:34, 35.

We should immediately observe three points about this text that are obvious:

- The women (or wives) being in subjection should be read in the context of ALL Christians being subject to one another (Eph 5:21)
- Paul’s instruction here does not mean that women (or wives) should remain silent in church or that they are forbidden to speak or preach.  1 Cor 11:5 makes this clear by providing instruction on how women were to speak and preach.
- The advice Paul gives is in the context of calming the rabble that had developed in Corinth as various “prophets” competed to speak in tongues and prophesy.  Thus it is not a plea for silence as much as for order as confirmed in 1 Cor 14:40, “let all things be done decently and in order”.

The "but if" (εἰ δέ) phrase at the beginning of V35 is significant.  Paul is discussing general chit-chat in church where people chat to one another and wives talk with their husband.  He is contrasting banning such general chit-chat in church with what is allowed at home.

That is, Paul does not forbid women to speak and preach in church, he only forbids women and others to talk among themselves while someone is presumably preaching or prophesying.  Only one person should speak at a time (V29-33).

Comment: "Paul’s instruction here does not mean that women (or wives) should remain silent in church or that they are forbidden to speak or preach" That is literally the entire point of the words "Women should remain silent in the churches. They are not allowed to speak .. for it is disgraceful for a woman to speak in the church"!

Comment: @SolaGratia - so, was Paul mistaken to include instructions about Women praying and prophesying in church?  We have the example of Luke 9:36 about people remining silent ((same verb) but speaking.  I think Paul's instruction in 1 Cor 14:34, 35 is about people remining silent while others are speaking as he says elesewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree verse 35 is an addition to verse 34, and not a restatement. Verse 34 is a principle telling the women should remain silent in the church. Whereas verse 35 is telling a specific act that the women should avoid talking to their husband in the church.

From verse 29 to 33, Paul was teaching the Corinthians should speak in order with respect. For verse 33 read

> For God is not a God of disorder but of peace—as in all the congregations of the Lord’s people.

Referring to this verse, I think Paul implied when the women talked, the whole church was too noisy and didn't have the peace and solemn to worship.

The conjunction used at the beginning of verse 35 refers to the act of the women (talking to their husband). It has no connection to verse 34.